# JAXB read XML Section into String

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to read a XML Section which looks like the following with JAXB:

```
<rootelem>
    <data>
      <param1>30</param1>
      <arg>8</arg>
    </data>
</rootelem>
```

My JAXB Data Class looks like so:

```
public class rootelem{

private final StringProperty data = new SimpleStringProperty();              

@XmlElement
public String getData() {
    return data.get();
}

public StringProperty dataProperty() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data.set(data);
}
}
```

The data String property should then contain the `<param1>30......</arg>` part.
When reading it in now, it produces "\n       " (stopping reading before the next tag). 
Any advice here is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data element is a complex type element as it contains other elements too.

Created a small sample example at:
https://github.com/snuniverse/StackoverflowExamples/tree/master/Test_61353696/src/com/test

Let me know if that helps.